# active support key generator, where is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, activesupport

Using Rails 4.0.1

I'm trying to generate a key to use with `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor` but I can't find how to require key_generator. I'm following this code: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html

This code throws an error:

```
key = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new('password').generate_key(salt)
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator
```

Requiring it doesn't work either:

```
require 'active_support/key_generator'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support/key_generator
```

Finally, googling yields no relevant results. Le tear.

Anybody used KeyGenerator before? How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

It exists starting from rails 4.0.0